# Sort Arraylists according to Dates with particular format

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that I want to sort multiple Arraylists with respect to Date Arraylist with a format as: 2011-07-18T10:39:32.144Z. How to that in java? Can anyone Help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the dates in your list Date objects, or String representations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the format of the date is irrelevant, as long as they are represented by the Date class.

Since Date implements Comparable, the standard sort of the Collections class should work.

Considering "dates" as your ArrayList, just do:
    Collections.sort(dates);

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Collections.sort(arrayListOfDates, new Comparator(){
                @Override
                public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                    Date date1=(Date)o1;
                    Date date2=(Date)o1;
                    if(date1.equals(date2))
                        return 0;
                    else if(date1.before(date2))
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
            });
```

It sorts the ArrayList Of dates and stores it in the same list

Comment: No generics and ignoring the fact that `Date` implements `Comparable`?

Comment: Useful for my problem +1